# Check a float value contains a minus sign (hyphen-minus) - Python

Tags: python

I just want to check the variable contains a negative value but it keeps throwing me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\...\...\file.py", line 88, in <module>
     main()
  File "C:\...\...\...\file.py", line 33, in main
     if '-' in done:
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

I have looked at others with similiar error but none of them gave me the idea to my current problem.

Still new to python and programming not having a good grasp on this.
Hopefully you can guide me in the right way.
Appreciate your help, folks!

I have done this so far:

```
def main():
   val = '-96000'

   flo = float(val)

   if '-' in flo:
       print('yes')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: You already have a floating point value. Check it before converting or just use `if flo < 0:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String characters don't exist in `float` objects. Just perform a numeric comparison:

```
if flo < 0:
    print('yes')
```

The keyword `in` is used to iterate an iterable object such as a `str` instance, so your logic would work with a string:

```
if '-' in val:
    print('yes')
```

Of course, in the second instance it's wiser to compare against the first character or the start of the string, e.g. `val[0] == '-'` or `val.startswith('-')`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the cast from `str` to `float`, so you can control the minus sign is present:

```
def main():
   val = '-96000'

   if '-' in val:
       print('yes')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Or better, control that the `str` actually begins with the minus sign:

```
   if val.startswith('-'):
       print('yes')
```

Or better, still cast to float, then control the value of your data:

```
def main():
   val = '-96000'
   flo = float(val)
   if flo < 0:
       print('yes')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```